# Vector or raster graphic for UI elements?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, icons, screen-resolution

Which type of graphic should I use for UI elements in web and mobile?
If I need to create @5x image size and then just reduce it or I need to create 1 vector image (like a button or icon) and just use this for all screen resolutions?

Comment: It would help to know a bit more about the context you're making this decision in. Perhaps you'll receive more specific suggestions :)

Comment: This isn't really a User Experience question. The end user doesn't care if you'e used a Vector or Raster image. So the issue you're having is with implementation, not with user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing UI elements use vector graphics.

Use raster only for photos.

If you use vectors the elements you design will maintain their sharpness at any resolution.

**EDIT:** (I thought it would be better to add the answer to your comments in here)

> I just want to understand which way create graphics.

**It depends.**
Vector and raster are different ways images are rendered on the screen.

With **raster** the image format stores the information of every pixel composing the image.

With **vector** the image format stores the position of each of the points of a path (and some other information; vector files can also include raster images). Then during render, the image shown on the screen is composed for each resolution.

There is no a "better" format, it depends on what is your goal.

Nowadays designers use software like Sketch, Figma, Adobe XD to design user interfaces because they render the images in a very similar way the browsers do. And they all work in vector.

**In conclusion:**
My advice would be to use the software you find yourself most comfortable with, and see how you go. The important thing is to start designing!
I am sure you will get familiar enough with UI Design that you will find the answer to this very question by yourself in no time :)

Comment: So it means that I don't need to create one button in size like 120x120px and then reduce it to 80x80 and 40x40 px? Just create 1 vector image and save it?
For example: iOS requires for me as designer create name@1x.png, name@2x.png etc

Comment: Alright, so do you have a list of specifications you need to follow?

Comment: You mean "alright" for this 'Just create 1 vector image and save it'?
For now I don't have any specifications to follow. I just learn and want to understand which way create graphics